# javascript how to get urls to files in folder from server?

Tags: javascript

I host a folder "/listings" on my jetty server.
I catch a file with a url to it

```
url = "/listings/file.json"
```

So i want to create an url like this for each file in this folder.

How can it be done in javascript?

Comment: You cannot do this simply by javascript

Comment: Actually, you *can* do it with Javascript but it would be a bad idea.  By enabled folder browsing on the web server you could then perform an AJAX call to get that listing and parse it.  However, you should really make a server-side function to handle this and then call *that* via an AJAX call instead.

Comment: @Archer i think i will choose this approach. Because the only alternative i had in mind would be generating html/js code which could be stressful

Comment: Enabling folder browsing is a very, very bad idea.  It gives people unrestricted access to all files in the included folders, which, if done not done carefully, would be your whole web server root folder (and sub-folders).

Comment: I would generate an endpoint, that gives just the list of the folders content in form of urls (strings).

Answer (score 0):

If you have server-side language on the server, see [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) and search for the server-side language methods to manage *files*, then use them to make changes in directories and files.

(with *XMLHttpRequest* you can run the server-side language file commands block)

Answer (score -1):

Your question isn't very clear to me.

Assuming the files are already on your server and your Javascript runs in a Node environment (and not a browser), you can use Express to serve this directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/listings'));

app.listen(3000);
```

After that, you can access your files at `http://your_domain.com:3000/listings/file.json

Does this answer your question?